# Read unknown symbols when read a content of file

Tags: c++, file-io

As in the title, when read a content of file i find it reads unknown symbols with the content.

**The code:**

```
char *buff = NULL;
size_t size = 0;    
ifstream file("c:\\file.txt", ios::out);

if(!file){
    cout << "File does not open." << endl;
}

file.seekg(0, file.end);
size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, file.beg);

buff = new char[size];
while(!file.eof()){
    file.read(buff, size);
}

cout << buff << endl;
delete[] buff;
```

**The file content:**

`Hello world!.
Thank you for help.`

**The result:**

[image]

As you seen in the previous image, there are many unknowns symbols.
Why these symbols appear, what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: You should alloc size+1 for buff and set last character to '/0' - that will solve problem. You don't load unknown characters, you just print trash going after buffer.

Comment: You should also null-terminate the string yourself. `read` reads bytes, not strings.

Comment: Even better would be using 'vector<char> buffer' for that, avoiding allocation of memory by 'new' operator.

Comment: I didn't get why you're passing `ios::out` to the input stream : `ifstream file("c:\\file.txt", ios::out);`. You can simply write `std::ifstream file("c:\\file.txt");`. Keep things simple!

Comment: If possible, please add a copy of at least some of the symbols into a code block in your question.  What encoding is used with the file that you are reading? Additionally, you want to consider this, or other similar solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138863/read-unicode-files

Comment: @Adam: Thanks, I have do `size+1` but I don't know how to set last character to '/0'  .

Comment: @LionKing No you don't. You have `buff = new char[size];` which, if you notice, is distinctly missing a `+1`. Once you fix that, add a `buff[size] = '\0';` after the `read()`.

Comment: @Adam: Good, works fine, but still appear the symbol `=`, for example: `Thank you for help.=`

Answer (score 3):

Your `char` array is not null terminated, either create the array with space for one extra null character (and set it to `'\0'`)

```
buff = new char[size + 1];
buff[size] = '\0';
// Or simply
buff = new char[size + 1]{};
```

or even better avoid using raw pointers wherever possible, *especially* for character arrays used as strings.

[`while(!file.eof())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) is an antipattern, don't use it except in very specific cases.

```
std::ifstream file("file.txt");
std::string buff{ // Use regular brackets if not C++11
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
};
```

Comment: `Your char array is not null terminated, either create the array with space for one extra null character (and set it to '\0')`, please I want an example if possible.

Comment: @LionKing added an example.

Comment: I have do it `buff = new char[size + 1];` but the symbols still appear. Also I'm use `visual studio 2010` and this `{}` does not work.

Comment: @LionKing Try `= {0};` instead. Also, paste the exact content of your text file in your question, and the output of `chcp`

Comment: Still does not Accepts `= {0}`, and what is the meaning of `chcp`.

Comment: @LionKing never mind, it looks like you weren't adding the `+1` after all according to your other comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `operator<<(const char *)` for C-style strings. You can't use it for arbitrary chunks of bytes. How would it know where to stop?

Comment: OP doesn't know the difference.

Comment: @Adam Which is a good reason to avoid using C-style strings and related concepts (such as `char *`) in C++ when possible.

Comment: I agree entirely. The trouble is that teaching materials for C++ are terrible. Newbies get introduced to this crap first and the proper C++ techniques are left for later.

Comment: What should happen is `std::copy` to `cout`. But who has the energy to properly explain those nuances to every fresh C++ kid struggling to make sense of what's been thrown at them?